# Listing the packages in a package group on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum

I'd like to see which packages are in the YUM group `Desktop` on CentOS 7. I am aware of the `yum group info` command, but it does not list any packages for the `Desktop` group. Why not?

When I run `yum group list` I see:

```
$ sudo yum group list
--snip--
Available Groups:
   --snip--
   Desktop
   --snip--
Done
```

When I run `yum group info fonts`, for example, I get lists of default and optional packages. With `Desktop` I get nothing:

```
$ sudo yum group info Desktop
--snip--
Group: Desktop
 Group-Id: basic-desktop
 Description: A minimal desktop that can also be used as a thin client.
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `sudo yum groupinfo Desktop`? (no space between group and info)

Comment: @DravSloan Both `groupinfo` and `group info` return the same results. The `yum` man page on CentOS 7 lists it with a space.

Comment: Strange. The Centos VM I have returns `No such command: group. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help` and a fully complete list of output for `groupinfo`. (maybe that's a difference on CentOS 6?)

Comment: From the man page: "groups -- A  command,  new  in 3.4.2, that collects all the subcommands that act on groups together."

Answer (score 6):

On RHEL/CentOS 6 it's `yum groupinfo` and on newer versions (since Fedora 19 if I remember correctly) it's `yum groups command` which is also reflected here: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumGroups and here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/YumGroupsAsObjects
Some more information on group handling here: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumGroupsOverview

One hint for that, one should always use `LC_ALL=C` and `-v` when operating on groups.
For one, it will show the original english names, and `-v` has two uses:

- it will show the "short names" for groups in brackets
- for `yum groupinfo <groupname>` or respectively `yum groups info <groupname>` it will show the packages from that group that are already installed and mark them with an @ (as in `yum list` output)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this doesn't really help explain which packages are in the Desktop group or why it exists.

Comment: Did you read the second wiki link? Maybe you should try with `LC_ALL=C yum -v --setopt=group_command=compat groups info desktop`

FWIW, just started a CentOS 7 x86_64 live KDE and the group "Desktop" does not exist there with the default base, extras and updates repos, also not in centosplus. If there are additional groups, you have to ask to the respective repository maintainers why they add empty groups.